# got exception when called applet at jsp/xhtml/html

Tags: java, applet

I got exception "ClassNotFoundException when call a applet at xhtml using JSF 2.0.I implemented two forms in applets.
These applet archived to console.jar file.These .jar file added into my web application classpath.The application was impelemnted in
JSF 2.0.The project struture like

```
scheamaconsole    
          |__src    
          |
          |__webapps
            |
            |____WEB-INF
             |
             |__lib
                 |
                 |__console.jar
             |
             |____ui
                |
                |__admin
                |
                |________ sechemaapplet.xhtml
```

schemaapplet.xml:-

```
<applet code="com.schema.apps.schemamain.class" width="100%" height="100%" archive="console.jar"  codebase="/classes/"/>
```

But above applet tag is not working.So i tried another way ,i copied console.jar file into webapps>ui and the applet code like

```
<applet code="com.schema.apps.schemamain.class" width="100%" height="100%" archive="console.jar"  codebase="/webapps/ui"/>
```

But this one also got same exception.Please help me, why got this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it resolved the issue.I copied all dependency .jars into ui>admin folder becuase client can be accessed only html,jsp etc resouces only.The applet tag is

```
<applet code="com.schema.apps.schemamain.class" width="100%" height="100%" archive="console.jar"  />
```